# Issue with date and inferSchema option in spark 3.1

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a CSV file with a date column as shown below,

```text
datecol
----------
2021-01-11
2021-02-15
2021-02-10
2021-04-22
```

If I read this file by enabling `inferSchema` in spark version 2.4.5 I'm getting below schema,

```
root
 |-- datecol: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

But in spark 3.1 below is the ouput.

```
root
 |-- datecol: string (nullable = true)
```

I have checked [migration guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/sql-migration-guide.html#upgrading-from-spark-sql-24-to-30) from spark documentation but didn't get any information about this.

Could anyone please confirm if it's a bug or do I need to use some other configurations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an effect of the Spark migration to Java 8 new Date API since Spark 3+. You can read from the [migration guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/sql-migration-guide.html#upgrading-from-spark-sql-24-to-30):

> Parsing/formatting of timestamp/date strings. This effects on CSV/JSON
> datasources [...]. New implementation performs strict checking of its input. For example,
> the `2015-07-22 10:00:00` timestamp cannot be parse if pattern is
> `yyyy-MM-dd` because the parser does not consume whole input. Another
> example is the `31/01/2015 00:00` input cannot be parsed by the
> `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm` pattern because `hh` supposes hours in the range 1-12.
> In Spark version 2.4 and below, java.text.SimpleDateFormat is used for
> timestamp/date string conversions [...].

In fact, [`inferSchema`](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/databricks/spark/csv/util/InferSchema.scala#L148) does not detect `DateType` but only `TimestampType`. And since by default in [CSV Data Source](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-csv.html), the parameter `timestampFormat` is `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss[.SSS][XXX]` then it is not converted  into timestamp for the reason cited above.

You can try to add the option when loading csv:

```scala
val df = spark.read.option("inferSchema", "true").option("timestampFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd").csv("/path/csv")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried with the option `timestampFormat` but it's inferring type as string only.

Comment: @MohanaBC did you specify `inferSchema = true` in options? I can get column inferred as timestamp using the above code.

Comment: Oh! I missed that. It's working after adding `inferSchema`!. Thanks.